# GAE(Python) simple Ajax call (can't figure out basic things needed to make this happen):

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, jquery

I'm using google app engine 1.8.0 (Python 2.7.5) and want to want to send the number to the server(Ajax), it will double it by multiplying and return the value.
What's wrong with the code? How to do this simple thing correctly? Checked online tutorials, but they are more like "simple guide how to build a wheel for mars rover in 6 easy steps":D
And yet the most basic simple thing is hard to grasp.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function TestingStuff() {

$.ajax({
url: "/DoubleMumbers",
type: "post",
data: { valueNr: $("data").val() },
success: function(){
  alert('succes!');
}
});
 }
</script>

<div>Enter the number:
<input id="data" type="text"/>
<input id="doubleNumber" type="button" onclick="TestingStuff()" value="Double">
<input id="result" type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code(separate copy from html code):**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
   function TestingStuff() {

   $.ajax({
   url: "/DoubleMumbers",
   type: "post",
   data: { valueNr: $("data").val() },
   success: function(){
       alert('succes!');
   }
   });
   }
</script>
```

**GAE code (Python):**

```
import webapp2


page = """ 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function TestingStuff() {

$.ajax({
url: "/DoubleMumbers",
type: "post",
data: { valueNr: $("data").val() },
success: function(){
   alert('succes!');
}
});
}
</script>

<div>Enter the number:
<input id="data" type="text"/>
<input id="doubleNumber" type="button" onclick="TestingStuff()" value="Double">
<input id="result" type="text"/>
</body>

</html>"""

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(page)

class DoubleNumbers(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write(valueNr*2)



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/DoubleNumbers', DoubleNumbers)
], debug=True)
```

There might be mistakes in the code, it's just that the head got already dizzy by trying to figure out the basic thing one needs to make this work. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the template code twice and the JS three times?

Comment: Just to separate diff codes for readability purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
url: "/DoubleMumbers",
```

It should be `"/DoubleNumbers"`

Comment: Your post() method uses `valueNr` but doesn't define it.  Add the line

    valueNr = self.request.POST['valueNr']

before you double it.

Comment: Everything makes sense now, thank you. Just one more thing. So how do i use the value in the response? As i understand, "success:' should be able to use the doubled number, but how..?

Comment: success: function(data){
  alert(data); }

Comment: You get in alert box:  undefinedundefinedundefined (3 times)

Comment: The problem was that alert box doesn't output the value (there's a workaround with this problem in Javascript, don't remember that). But it will output it if you would do it in the following manner:
success: function(responseText){
   $("#result").html("Successful Request! "+ responseText);}

And you should cast the variable (on the server side) to int,so the final code for server side response is the following:
def post(self):
   valueNr = self.request.POST['valueNr']
   blabla = int(valueNr)*2
   self.response.write(blabla)